# angular 2 cant call function inside function it says its not a function

Tags: angular, vaadin

i have angular 2 client
on the component.ts i create an ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit(){

        var grid = document.getElementById('devpro');
        grid.addEventListener('selected-items-changed', function() {

                var selected = grid.selection.selected();
                if (selected.length == 1) {

                    this.detailproject = [];
                    var prodetails = grid.items[grid.selection.selected()].ProjectName;
                    console.log(prodetails);
                    this.getdetailsproject(prodetails);   <<<<<< this part
                    var detailsproject :any = document.getElementById('detailsproject');
                        if (detailsproject) {
                            detailsproject.open();
                        }
                }
        });
    }


getdetailsproject(prodetails){ <<< this is my function
        this._httpprovider.httpReq('http://localhost:5000/getdetailsproject','POST',{ProjectName:prodetails},null).subscribe((data)=>{ 
                    var dprodetails = [];
                    for (let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    dprodetails.push(data[i]);
                    }
                    this.detailproject = dprodetails;        
            });
    }
```

i try to call it inside and nothing come out its just an error say that my getdetailsproject is not an function

is there a way to call it like normal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in type script use

```
grid.addEventListener('selected-items-changed', () => { })
```

instead of

```
grid.addEventListener('selected-items-changed', function() { });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. But the problem is js functionality. If u are putting  console.log(prodetails); within your function then it will be working like charm. You are placed this next to function,so js automatically call the console before executing the getdetailsproject() function. Use this

```js
getdetailsproject(prodetails){ <<< this is my function
        this._httpprovider.httpReq('http://localhost:5000/getdetailsproject','POST',{ProjectName:prodetails},null).subscribe((data)=>{ 
                    var dprodetails = [];
                    for (let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    dprodetails.push(data[i]);
                    }
                    this.detailproject = dprodetails;        
                    console.log(this.detailproject);
            });
    }
```

then you can make another function to call the rest functionalities. Note : Javascript/typescript not work step by step.It doesn't wait for any response delay